# How to install a Code snippet extension as dev dependency in package.json

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is it possible to install [React Code Snippet extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets) as a dev dependency inside package.json?

I want my other team-mates to have this when they clone my project and execute: npm install.

Otherwise, everyone has to install manually from VS-Code Marketplace extension manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple ways you could go about this. If you want the installation script to be in your `package.json`, then you would have to add it to the script block (Option 1).  `devDependencies` only installs packages into `node_modules` and will not have any ability to install IDE extensions.

**I would recommend Option 2 for a slightly more automated approach that only requires the user to click `Install` on the toast prompt.**

---

**Option 1 : Install by running a `npm` script:**

In your `package.json` file, find your scripts block and add the `ext` line from below to the end of it.

```json
"scripts": {
    "<your-other-scripts>": "...",
    "ext": "code --install-extension dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets"
},
```

All they would have to do is execute `npm run ext` in their terminal and the extension will install or update on their IDE.

> Not that this still requires the user to run a command manually that is not a standard command.

---

**Option 2 : Recommended Extension:**

If you don't already have a `.vscode` directory in your project, create one and inside of it create an `extensions.json` file.  Inside that file, you can list any extensions that your project recommends to the developer working on it.  Add the following snippet and save and reload:

```json
{
  "recommendations": ["dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets"]
}
```

Now, when you navigate to the Extensions Marketplace, that extension and any others you add to the array in that file will appear in the recommended extensions section.

[image]

They will also be prompted when opening the project if they want to install the extension to their IDE if it is not already installed.

[image]

Hope you find this helpful!